# Create SDK in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, sdk

I want to create an SDK for iOS and Android apps for service layer(basically backend interaction) in React Native. Output from the SDK should be either .a or .framework file, which can be imported in any iOS native app. I have 2 questions:

1. Is it a good approach to create SDK in React Native?
2. How to create it?

Thanks

Comment: What would be your preferred language? Cross platform C++? Do you need to access UI components?

Comment: UI in swift/kotlin and SDK in React Native.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Any Solution you found on this ? or what was your final decision ?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: were u able to get a good solution

Comment: To everyone who is asking about final decision: I end up building a React Native version. However it was not a framework or library but actual source code from a different repository. UI was in Kotlin/Swift. 

So we had common code in React Native  for all backend interactions and native UI for IOS and Android were consuming that.

Answer (score -2):

Some good reasons to publish an SDK as a React Native module:

- **Expose the SDK to a large community of developers**: This could be good if you're trying to gain some reputation or expand your experience. Also if you are providing a quick start to a commercial product you wish to grow, for example an SAAS API or a hardware peripheral. Another good reason to do this is to leverage crowdsourced development.
- **Provide implementations on multiple platforms**: RN allows a developer to share code across platforms. A "top" layer abstracts business and presentation logic, leaving OS specific code to the internal implementation of each module (for example your SDK). This is important if you need access to device facilities like a camera or bluetooth, because the native implementations will be different, but using RN you can unify interfaces and save around.
- **UI model has a more modern approach**: RN uses uses a functional style of programming that is naturally less error prone. Coming from a object oriented background can make RN a bit confusing to begin with, but in the end the state abstractions that are intrinsic to RN provide a large benefit in readability and code organization when it comes to UI. Developing UI in both iOS and Android requires knowledge of the platform specific idiosyncrasies and conventions, which helps for RN but is not necessary. As an SDK module you'll be expected to provide a typical RN interface to your binary, that uses those principles.

Some Bad Reasons:

- **It's easier**: RN is easier for simple apps that want to have a multi-platform presence, but a lot of the difficulties of developing for each platform will still be there. For example, you still need to know about provisioning profiles to deploy an app to the apple app store.

How to get started:
Read the react native documentation on native modules for [Android](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) and [iOS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios)